# Library to analyse sound

Tags: c++, audio

I need in analyzing system output sound runtime. OS: Linux. The first thing I need is get different frequency values. Programming language: c++.

Comment: There are lots of ways to do a fast fourier transform. What are your source and destination data formats?

Comment: Formats of what? I just need to get master-output channel and analyse it's frequency.

Comment: Trying to hijack the operating system's speaker output is probably the most difficult and least portable thing you could ask for. (But maybe it's easier on Linux, I don't know.) Can you just implement a pipe from whatever is generating the audio?

Comment: @Potatoswatter, no I can't. There is not only 1 source of music but several.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One semi-portable* way that comes to mind for grabbing all the sound from multiple sources is PulseAudio. (In this case, semi-portable means working with many sound cards, not working with different OSes, though there is a WinXP version of PulseAudio). One of the [PulseAudio modules](http://pulseaudio.org/wiki/Modules#module-pipe-sink) provides a pipe sink. Hopefully all your outputs will be PulseAudio-compatible - nearly everything that plays nice with ALSA should be fine. You should then be able to just read from that pipe to get your input.

You can then use a library like [FFTW](http://www.fftw.org/) (first suggested by Thomas' answer) for fast Fourier transform, assuming this is what you mean by 'get the frequency values'.

<sub>*In this case, semi-portable means working with many sound cards, not working with different OSes, though there is a WinXP version of PulseAudio (haven't tried it myself).</sub>

Answer (score 1):

The question is a bit vague, but here's some potentially useful information.

PCM-encoded WAV files are [pretty easy to parse](https://ccrma.stanford.edu/courses/422/projects/WaveFormat/); you don't really need a library for that.

For the frequency analysis, I would use [FFTW](http://www.fftw.org/) to do the Fourier transform.

Comment: And what about grabbing music from given source?

Comment: What kind of source? An MP3 file? A webcast? A microphone input?

Comment: In Windows, that would depend on the sound card; not all cards offer an input that "loops back" the sound sent to the speakers. In Linux, I don't have a clue. Maybe you should edit your question to be more specific.